# Find minimal candidate keys

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

I have 2 sets

```
R = {A B C D}
H = {AB-> C , AB-> D, D-> B}
```

Want to find all minimal keys in R set

My answer for minimal keys is : { A D }

this is because

```
AB -> C and AB -> D then AB -> CD
since D -> B then AD is the minimal keys
```

when i check my answer with this [site](http://www.koffeinhaltig.com/fds/kandidatenschluessel.php?attrs=A&fds=AB-%3EC,AB-%3ED,D-%3EB&language=en). the site giving wrong answer. 
can explain?

Comment: The site is clearly wrong. Edit your question, and include step-by-step how you got your answer. Also include the title of the textbook you're following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site says, "Set of found candidate-keys: {{A, C, F}, {B, C, F}}." That's clearly wrong; F isn't even *in* R.

In any case, your answer is incomplete. AD is one of two candidate keys.

Comment: so only have two candidate keys in my set?

Comment: Yes, only two candidate keys, based on the functional dependencies H={AB->C , AB->D, D->B}.

Comment: isn't another set of candidate key is { A C } ? i keep do and redo again

Comment: No, AC isn't a candidate key. Follow my advice in my comment to your question.  It will save you time and frustration, *and* you'll get better answers. (And probably *more* answers, too.)

Comment: i just know how to find A D, another 1 not sure .. can teach?

Comment: To find all the candidate keys, you compute the "closure of a set of functional dependencies". (You can Google that. It's probably off-topic here, because it would take a chapter-length answer.)